# When did John Boone first land on Mars

Tags: character-development, mars-trilogy

Kim Stanley Robinson's Red Mars gives a very specific date early in the book of 21st December 2026 as the launch date of the Ares mission and the start of the first hundred's journey.

What I can't seem to find is the date of John Boone's first trip to Mars, when he became the 'First Man on Mars' which is such an important part of his back story and influence over all the other colonists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My edition (Voyager, paperback, 1996) has a timeline at the end of the book (p671) that says the first landing was in 2020 - six years before the *Ares* left for Mars.

Confoundingly, the blurb text on the back of the book states 2019 as the year Boone first steps on Mars. This same blurb appears in a promotion for the book in The Martians (Voyager, paperback, 2000).

I don't recall anything more specific being mentioned.